# Does Krita have a hex color selector? Where do I find it?

Tags: color, krita

I'm doing some webdev stuff, and I'm creating some designs in Krita. Since CSS mostly uses hex values (aside some hard-coded ones), I need to access the color hex values.

The Krita color pickers come with a color wheel and sliders, but nothing for hex values. It should be in the specific color picker, as mentioned [in the forums](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=95027), but it doesn't seem to show up there either.

How do I use the hex color selector?

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you're doing the whole design in Krita or how plausible it is for web development, but my instincts are saying it might not be so great for that. — I would super urge you to try out [Webflow](https://webflow.com/). You can make at least one private design (with the free plan), which you can delete and make a new one in its place once you are done. You can't export the site with the free account, other than copy the code of the front page, I believe, but I've personally used it sort of like I used to use Photoshop; just for the design and then code the site by hand.

Comment: I mostly use Krita to design it before I write code. I need to access hex values to import and export values before I write the CSS (and to preview it in Krita). I could of course do it in a browser and just run it like that, but I prefer doing the concept design in programs like Krita. I'll still check it out though, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: I've never used the code it generates in production because it's unnecessarily bulky, but it's ammmaaaazing for designing a site. I'd claim it's the best experience you can get out of designing a website in the browser (or perhaps in general). Like adjusting colors and styles works just the same as it does for websites normally. If elements share the same class, they share the same style. Also, elements that grow in height push the content below them so you don't have to move things around like crazy after changing a few things here and there (as long as the structure makes sense).

Comment: This question resurfaced and I remembered thinking... maybe this doesn't help in this situation, but… on mac specifically, I use 3rd party OS wide color pickers. Here's a list of few: [ColorSnapper](https://colorsnapper.com/), [Sip](http://sipapp.io/) — The next two I've not used: [Contrast](https://usecontrast.com/), [Kelir](https://rimbunesia.com/apps/kelir-color-picker-for-mac/). — Each of these can give you the hex code for a color you picked anywhere in the OS. My preference is ColorSnapper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is in the specific color selector, but it is only available for 8 bit color spaces. To enable it, change the depth to 8 bits instead of 16:

[image]

Also note that "Show Colorspace Selector" needs to be checked to access the option.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the method stated in selected answer. You can also change or see the hex code in the color selector you get from double clicking on the foreground color box in the top tool bar

[image]